# C# Decompress .GZip to file

Tags: c#

I have this Code

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
...
UnGzip2File("input.gz","output.xls");
```

Which run this procedure, it runs without error but after it, the input.gz is empty and created output.xls is also empty. At the start input.gz had 12MB. What am i doing wrong ? Or have you better/functional solution ?

```
public static void UnGzip2File(string inputPath, string outputPath) 
        {
            FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputPath, FileMode.Create);
            FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create);

            using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(inputFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
                int n;

                // To be sure the whole file is correctly read, 
                // you should call FileStream.Read method in a loop, 
                // even if in the most cases the whole file is read in a single call of FileStream.Read method.

                while ((n = gzipStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    outputFileStream.Write(bytes, 0, n);
                }
            }

            outputFileStream.Dispose();
            inputFileStream.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: When you open a file to read you shouldn't use `Create` option.

Comment: Make sure to use `using` for all resources. I don't know why people still don't do that in 2014 although there are no disadvantages for doing that.

Comment: usr: Okay, thanks for a tip. I find that advantage of using block is it dispose even in error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening the `FileStream` with the `FileMode.Create` will overwrite the existing file as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx). This will cause the file to be empty when you try to decompress it, which in turn leads to an empty output-file.

Below is a working code sample, note that it is async, this can be changed by leaving out async/await and changing the call to the regular CopyTo-method and changing the return type to void.

```
public static async Task DecompressGZip(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{
    using (var input = File.OpenRead(inputPath))
    using (var output = File.OpenWrite(outputPath))
    using (var gz = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        await gz.CopyToAsync(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, its a lot easier.